# How can I fix my textfield to properly send requests to my API

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I'm a little bit confused on how I can get my `textfield` component to send ***input*** data (correctly/validated) from React to my API server. My backend is receiving the requests, but I'm not actually sure what is being sent over within my request.

To go into deeper detail, I'm trying to send a `PATCH` request to my `stock_list` JSON field. The data within the patch request is then selected by the user, which should be `option.symbol` from the `textfield`

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import Axios from "axios";
import axiosInstance from '../../../axios';
import { useParams } from 'react-router-dom';
import Autocomplete from '@material-ui/lab/Autocomplete';
import { makeStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import TextField from '@material-ui/core/TextField';
import Button from '@material-ui/core/Button';

export default function SymbolInput() {
    const { slug } = useParams();
    const initialFormData = Object.freeze({
      stock_list: '',
  });
    const [formData, updateFormData] = useState(initialFormData);

    const handleChange = (e) => {
        updateFormData({
            ...formData,
        });
    };

    const handleSubmit = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        console.log(formData);

        axiosInstance
            .patch(`bucket/symbols/` + slug + '/', {
                stock_list: formData.stock_list,
            })
            .then((res) => {
               // history.push('/');
                console.log(res);
                console.log(res.data);
            });
    };      
    const [data, setData] = useState({ companies: [] });

    const classes = useStyles();

    useEffect(() => {
        Axios.get("https://app.stockbuckets.io/tickers/").then((res) => {
            setData({ companies: res.data });
        });
    }, [setData]);
    

    return (
        <div className={classes.root}>
          <form>
            <Autocomplete
                multiple
                options={data.companies}
                filterSelectedOptions
                onChange={handleChange}
                getOptionLabel={(option) => option.symbol} 
                renderOption= {(option) => option.symbol + ' | ' +  option.company}
                getOptionSelected={(option) => option.symbol} 
                renderInput={(params) => (
                <TextField
                    {...params}
                    id="stock_list"
                    name="stock_list"
                    variant="outlined"
                    label="Companies"
                />
                )}
            />
          </form> 
          <Button 
            variant="contained" 
            color="primary"
            onClick={handleSubmit}
          >
            Add Stocks
          </Button>
        </div>
    );
}
```

Here are my errors:

> xhr.js:177 PATCH http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/bucket/symbols/x8xkgafkm4/ 500 (Internal Server Error)

Yes I am getting an error from the backend, to start solving why I first want to see what data is actually being sent over.

```
createError.js:16 Uncaught (in promise) Error: Request failed with status code 500
    at createError (createError.js:16)
    at settle (settle.js:17)
    at XMLHttpRequest.handleLoad (xhr.js:62)
```

How can I debug/fix my code so I can at least console.log the data being sent over by my `textfield` when a user pushes my `button` component. Thank you for the help.

EDIT: It looks like nothing is being sent in the payload `PATCH` request, how may I go about solving this?

Comment: You can check the netwok comunication in developer tools, on chrome an firefox. To start press F12.

Comment: Thank you, I see now. The payload request seems to be empty.

Comment: Managing forms with react is a lot easier with something like [react-hook-form](https://react-hook-form.com/advanced-usage/) or `Formik`.

Comment: I've fixed my code around, now I'm not able to get the data in textfield within my JSON payload that's loaded with `stock_list` field.